# Remove rows with checked checkbox in tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I have created a tablelayoutpanel with two columns and three rows. I would like to create a delete button to delete rows with check in checkbox. Here is my code. However, the code does not work.

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)c;
                if (cb.Checked == true)
                {
                    tableLayoutPanel1.RemoveAt(cb)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What happens, or doesn't happen? Are there errors?

Comment: What does 'does not work' mean?  Is it complaining that you are breaking the enumeration?